# The more tablixes the slower the report runs?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I apologize if this has already been answered, but did a search and could not find anything.

So, I've been working in SSRS and have made some parameters that display a different tablix depending on the options selected; for example, if the user does not want to display both the original AND actual expiration date, I have a parameter to display one of the two tablixes. I may need to add one or two more tablixes though because I wanted to implement an "order by" parameter (I couldn't get it to work in my actual SQL code).

Does having numerous tablixes affect performance? I do not want my reports to be bogged down! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of tablixes is not a significant factor in performance imo. The main cause for performance issues would be 
1) SQL performance
2) slow performing library functions or procedures

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will keep those main performance issue causes in mind. :)